# Pushing mysql results into php array and printing this array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I am trying to make a code that gets an input and then starts comparing all values of this input with every other value of the other values in the database.
To do this i want to put every row in an array an then compare this array to the value of the input. Now my problem is that i cannot get an entire row into an array the code that has the problem is.

```
 $row = array();
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$autorange2="SELECT AutoRange  FROM $tbl_name WHERE Nr='$i'";
$auto2=mysql_query($autorange, 0);
array_push($row, "$auto2");
}
print_r($row);
```

and my result is

```
Array ( [0] => Resource id #6 [1] => Resource id #7 [2] => Resource id #8 [3] =>  
Resource id #9 [4] => Resource id #10 [5] => Resource id #11 [6] 
=> Resource id #12 [7] => Resource id #13 [8] => Resource id #14 [9] => 
Resource id #15 )
```

(the print is for testing purposes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to outut `$row` — result set. You can't output result set, you have to fetch it firstly.

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` function for it.

```
$row = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 $autorange2="SELECT AutoRange  FROM $tbl_name WHERE Nr='$i'";
 $auto2=mysql_query($autorange); // <-- I removed 2nd parameter, you don't need it there
 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($auto2)) {
  $row[] = $data; // same as array_push($row, $data);
  // $data['AutoRange']; <-- get access to data on this row
 }
 print_r($row);
}
```

If you want to directly access to some entry in set, use `$data['fieldName']` where `fieldName` is name of field you want to acess.

`mysql_fetch_assoc` return associated array.

**Note**: if you will use method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278314/2898694) answer you have to know, that `mysql_fetch_array` returns indexed array, so you have to get access to data with `$data[0]`, `$data[1]` etc. I think better to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` function and work with associative array.

**Another note**: what for you use such approach to work with database? You don't need `for` loop to get data from table. Data, returned in resultset, depending on your query.

This query will return all rows from table `$tbl_name`:

```
SELECT AutoRange  FROM $tbl_name
```

So your code will be:

```
$rows = array();
$autorange2="SELECT AutoRange  FROM $tbl_name WHERE Nr='$i'";
$auto2=mysql_query($autorange); // <-- I removed 2nd parameter, you don't need it there
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($auto2)) {
 $rows[] = $data; // same as array_push($row, $data);
 // $data['AutoRange']; <-- get access to data on this row
}
print_r($rows);
```

Now you have values of `autorange` field of each row from `$tbl_name` table.

How you get access to this data:

```
foreach($row in $rows) {
 $autoRange = $row['AutoRange'];
 var_dump($autoRange);
}
```

Comment: I now get this error message Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, integer given in C:\wamp\www\lol.php on line 34

Comment: @user3527915 Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) page (also read warning section) for it. I assume, you don't need this parameter. Just use `mysql_query($autorange);`

Comment: Also, why you work so with your database? What you want to achieve by this approach? I mean loop, which is working 10 times. What for?

Comment: Good practise is to give descriptive names. put your sql query to `$sqlQuery` variable. `myslq_query()` function will return result set, so give the variable, in which you will put result of `mysql_query` function, name `$resultset`. Etc etc etc.

Comment: @user3527915 tell me if my answer and this advices wouldn't help you.

Comment: Using the link that you gave me and the anwser you gave me i managed to solve my problems thank you

Comment: Nice. One more question. Why you do execute your sql query in `for` loop? Is it neccessary for you application?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_array`. Try this-

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   $autorange2="SELECT AutoRange  FROM $tbl_name WHERE Nr='$i'";
   $auto2=mysql_query($autorange, 0);
   while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($auto2))
   {
       array_push($row, $row1);
   }
}
```

And if you are sure that there will only be 1 row in the query result-

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   $autorange2="SELECT AutoRange  FROM $tbl_name WHERE Nr='$i'";
   $auto2=mysql_query($autorange, 0);
   array_push($row, mysql_fetch_assoc($auto2));
}
```